What could be causing my Celery Task to not be able to use my Mysql database connection?
I'm fairly new with celery & created some simple tasking operations using Celery, Redbeat, Flask, some basic duo auth, and a MySQL database. Only issue is that in a task it cannot connect to my database due to it thinking the connecting string is None values like the errors details below
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'None' ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)


I checked over how I set up Celery, and it seems fine. when starting the application all of the variables used also seem fine. Outside of tasks, I can use the database correctly. So I'm thinking I somehow messed up part of the configuration that is preventing tasks in their context from being unable to access the database connection, but I can't seem to pinpoint it. If anyone could offer me an extra set of eyes to see where the issue is/why it's occurring, I'd be grateful. I've attached the setup code below and the relevant task code that fails.
Here is application.py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from flask_cors import CORS
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
import config.const as CONSTANTS
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
from extensions import db, jwt, ma, socketio
from web.authentication import auth
from web.tasks import tasks
from celery_config import make_celery

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY=CONSTANTS.SECRET,
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=CONSTANTS.DB_CONNECTION_STRING,
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,
        PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME='https',
        CELERY_BROKER_URL=f'{CONSTANTS.broker_dev}',
        CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=f'{CONSTANTS.backend_dev}'
    )

    CORS(app)
    app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1, x_host=1, x_port=1, x_prefix=1)

    # Initialize and register all Flask extensions
    db.init_app(app)
    jwt.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

    # OAuth configuration
    oauth = OAuth(app)
    app.config['GOTO'] = oauth.register(
        'goto',
        client_id=CONSTANTS.CLIENT_ID,
        authorize_url='CONSTANT.AUTH_URL',
        authorize_params=None,
        access_token_params=None,
        refresh_token_url=None,
        redirect_uri='https://e6d8-70-57-86-187.ngrok-free.app'
    )


    # Register all application blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/auth')
    app.register_blueprint(tasks, url_prefix='/task')

    # Celery configuration
    app.celery = make_celery(app)


    return app


Here is celery_config.py
from celery import Celery
import config.const as CONST

def make_celery(app):
    backend = CONST.backend_dev
    broker = CONST.backend_dev


    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=backend, broker=broker)
    celery.conf.update({
        'broker_url': app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
        'result_backend': app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        'sqlalchemy_database_uri': app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'],
        'beat_scheduler': 'redbeat.RedBeatScheduler',
        'redbeat_redis_url': backend,
        'redbeat_key_prefix': 'redbeat:',
        'beat_max_loop_interval': 10,
        'beat_schedule': {},
        'imports': ('tasks.celery_tasks',)
    })
    celery.set_default()
    app.extensions['celery'] = celery
    if app is not None:
        class ContextTask(celery.Task):
            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                with app.app_context():
                    print("Task is running with app context")
                    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
        celery.Task = ContextTask

    return celery

And make_celery.py where I start the application
from flask import redirect, url_for, request

from application import create_app

app = create_app()
celery_app = app.extensions['celery']
celery_app.control.purge()


@app.route("/")
def default_route():
    print("This print statements means we hit our default route in make celery")
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, port=5009)


And finally here is the task section that is failing. When it attempts to query the Token (I'm using sqlalchemy) it throws the error.
@shared_task(name="run_http_task")
def run_http_task(task_id=None, task_url=None, task_name=None, search_string=None, success_text=None, fail_text=None, phone_number=None):
    token = Token.query.first()

